# oracle XE 18c inmemory settings

Tags: oracle, in-memory-database

I try to this in oracle XE 18c.
I cant't alter inmemory_size property but can alter sga_target.
Who relieve me?

```
SQL> alter system set inmemory_size=200M;
alter system set inmemory_size=200M
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02097: parameter cannot be modified because specified value is invalid
ORA-02095: specified initialization parameter cannot be modified

SQL> alter system set sga_target=1024M;

System altered.
```

Answer (score 0):

`inmemory_size` can not be modified online. Modify it in the spfile:

`alter system set inmemory_size=200M scope=spfile;`

Then restart the database.